# Pass variable within a cypher query in Shiny R

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher

I will like to pass variable within the cypher query in Shiny R.
The R version that I am using is R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06) and neo4j-community-3.1.1

There is no issue retrieving the data from neo4j DB via below cypher query in Shiny R

```
query = "MATCH p=()-[:Month]->()-[:Day]->(d:Day)-[Hour]->(h:Hour)<-[timerel:CONNECTED_ON]-(n:IP)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(k:IP) WHERE h.hour=\"9\" and d.day=\"2\" RETURN p limit 25

cypher(graph, query)
```

However, when I attempt to pass variable into the cypher query based on what I have read in http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/, I encountered this error message:
"Warning: Error in : Client error: (400) Bad Request
Neo.ClientError.Statement.ParameterMissing
Expected a parameter named day"

```
day = "2"
hour = "9"
query = "MATCH p=()-[:Month]->()-[:Day]->(d:Day)-[Hour]->(h:Hour)<-[timerel:CONNECTED_ON]-(n:IP)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(k:IP) WHERE h.hour=$hour and d.day=$day RETURN p limit 25
```

I have also tried the following:

1: Putting {$hour}

```
day = "2"
hour = "9"    
query = "MATCH p=()-[:Month]->()-[:Day]->(d:Day)-[Hour]->(h:Hour)<-[timerel:CONNECTED_ON]-(n:IP)-[:CONNECT_TO]->(k:IP) WHERE h.hour={$hour} and d.day={$day} RETURN p limit 25
```

2: Putting {hour}

All the above does not allow me to pass variable into the cypher query statement.
Appreciate it if anyone can guide me on that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question for the sharing purpose, below 2 urls serve to address the method on how to pass variable in using Rneo4j

https://rdrr.io/cran/RNeo4j/man/cypher.html
https://github.com/nicolewhite/RNeo4j/blob/master/man/cypher.Rd

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `query` argument of `cypher()` is expecting a string. Use [glue](http://glue.tidyverse.org/) to compose the string.